# Clean thesis template, references not compressed

Tags: biblatex, cleanthesis

I'm using Clean Thesis template for my thesis. My problem is: "the references are not compressed," as shown in the highligted line segment in the image below. Could anyone please suggest how the issue can be addressed? Thanks a million.

And, here is the code that configure the bibliography system:

```
\usepackage[
    figuresep=colon,
    sansserif=false,
    hangfigurecaption=false,
    hangsection=true,
    hangsubsection=true,
    colorize=full,
    bibsys=bibtex,
    bibfile=bib-refs,
    bibstyle=numeric
    bibliographystyle=ieeetr
]{cleanthesis}
```

[image]

Comment: What bibliography system is used by your template?

Comment: Hi, Dr. Manuel. I'm using BibTeX system.

Comment: Please post the code that configures BiBTeX.

Comment: % I'm not sure if this is what you asked. \usepackage[     % clean thesis style
 figuresep=colon,%
 sansserif=false,%
 hangfigurecaption=false,%
 hangsection=true,%
 hangsubsection=true,%
 colorize=full,%
 %colortheme=bluegreen%
 %colortheme=bluemagenta,%
 bibsys=bibtex,%
 bibfile=bib-refs,%
 bibstyle=numeric%authoryear%alphabetic%numeric%;
]{cleanthesis}

Comment: Add it to your question -- not as a comment. Maybe read https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228 first.

Comment: I tried to clean the code -- please help by removing the `%` that are not needed.

Comment: Looking at the [clean thesis.sty](https://github.com/derric/cleanthesis/blob/master/cleanthesis.sty) it seems as if you are using the `biblatex` package with `bibtex` backend. You could copy the .sty file to the directory where your .tex file is and replace line 286: `style=\cthesis@bibstyle`by `style=numeric-comp` as originally suggested by @ Dr. Manuel Kuehner. Maybe this helps.

Comment: I tried as Dr. Manuel suggested. It didn't work. I also combined his with your suggestion, it still didn't work. Here what was returned after running: ! Package xkeyval Error: value `numeric-comp' is not allowed. Thank you both a lot for trying to help.

Comment: I'm sorry there was a mistake in my comment. The option should be `citestyle=numeric-comp` instead of `style=numeric-comp`.

Comment: It worked with more changes on these lines (replace "numeric" with numeric-comp): \define@choicekey*[ct]{cthesis}{bibstyle}[\val\bibstylenr]{numeric-comp,alphabetic,authoryear}[numeric-comp]{\def\cthesis@bibstyle{#1}}
\setkeys[ct]{cthesis}{bibstyle=numeric-comp}          % Thanks a million, Dr. Manuel & leandriis :)

Answer (score 2):

The [cleanthesis.sty](https://github.com/derric/cleanthesis/blob/master/cleanthesis.sty) uses `biblatex` to manage citations. While `biblatex` itself offers a broad variety of `citationstyles`, `cleanthesis` offers only three of them: `alphabetic`, `numeric` and `authoryear` to choose from using the `style=...` option from `cleanthesis`.

In order to use citationstyles other than the above mentioned, one can edit a local copy of `cleanthesis.sty` in the following two ways:

### 1. fixed citestyle, not customizable via option

The first customization option is to directly pass the desired citationstyle as an option to biblatex. Consider the following code, which is a copy of line 284-300 from `cleanthesis.sty`.

```
\RequirePackage[                    % use biblatex for bibliography
    backend=\cthesis@bibsys,        %   - use biber backend (bibtex replacement) or bibtex
    style=\cthesis@bibstyle,        %   - use alphabetic (or numeric) bib style
    natbib=true,                    %   - allow natbib commands
    hyperref=true,                  %   - activate hyperref support
    backref=true,                   %   - activate backrefs
    isbn=false,                     %   - don't show isbn tags
    url=false,                      %   - don't show url tags
    doi=false,                      %   - don't show doi tags
    urldate=long,                   %   - display type for dates
    maxnames=3,%
    minnames=1,%
    maxbibnames=5,%
    minbibnames=3,%
    maxcitenames=2,%
    mincitenames=1%
]{biblatex}
```

Replacing `style=\cthesis@bibstyle` by `citestyle=numeric-copm` (or every other citestyle `biblatex` offers) and **not** using `clearthesis`'s `bibstyle=...` option in the preamble of the document should work.

### 2. flexible citestyle, customizable via option

A better and more flexible approach is the following. 
The following code is again copied from `cleanthesis.sty` (line 92).

```
\define@choicekey*[ct]{cthesis}{bibstyle}[\val\bibstylenr]
{alphabetic,numeric,authoryear}[alphabetic]{\def\cthesis@bibstyle{#1}}
```

To customize this one could add the `numeric-comp` style (or any other) as follows:

```
\define@choicekey*[ct]{cthesis}{bibstyle}[\val\bibstylenr] alphabetic,numeric,authoryear,numeric-comp}[alphabetic]{\def\cthesis@bibstyle{#1}}
```

Now the added style can be chosen in the preamble of the .tex file using something like:

```
\usepackage[bibstyle=alphabetic,bibfile=filename]{cleanthesis}
```